# How to fix VBA Error "Cannot saving ".xlsm" to ".xlsx""?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm dividing a workbook in several stores.

I choose the store I want to see, and the code filters the data of the other stores and deletes that data, only leaving the data of the choosen store.

and after this I want to make a new workbook, saving as my ".xlsm" file to ".xlsx"

But after runing the code i have a pop up message asking if i want "to continue saving as a macro-free workbook"

If i click yes, i have a error saying:

> 1004 VB Projects and XLM sheets cannot be saved in a macro-free
>   workbook

What can i do to fix it?

this is the code to save the new workbook:

```
Dim Fname As String

Fname = "02.VIM_REPORT MENSAL - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V2") & " - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V3") & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

Comment: you got the fileFormat parameter wrong. You are saving xml format.

Comment: But when i search for the fileformat the "Open XML Workbook" is for ".xlsx" extensions...

Comment: Check my answer below. There are several formats that use the .xlsx extension: see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that code line to:
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault`

Answer (score 2):

just disable Alerts.

try with

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Fname As String

Fname = "02.VIM_REPORT MENSAL - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V2") & " - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V3") & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the help on the pop ups. With this and the file format change, its working :)